# Como formatear Rut chileno con puntos y guion al ingresarlo en el input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Al ingresar un rut este es validado, pero quisiera formatearlo para que al ingresarlo quede con el formato **`1.234.567-8`** o **`12.345.678-9`**

He intentado de esta forma:

```js
function validaRut(rut){ 
  var suma=0; 
  var arrRut = rut.split("-"); 
  var rutSolo = arrRut[0]; 
  var verif = arrRut[1]; 
  var continuar = true; 
  for(i=2;continuar;i++){ 
    suma += (rutSolo%10)*i; 
    rutSolo = parseInt((rutSolo /10)); 
    i=(i==7)?1:i; 
    continuar = (rutSolo == 0)?false:true; 
  }
   resto = suma%11; dv = 11-resto; 
   if(dv==10){  
      if(verif.toUpperCase() == 'K') return true;
   }else if (dv == 11 && verif == 0)
    return true; 
    else if (dv == verif) return true; 
    else alert("RUT incorrecto, ingréselo en el formato 11111111-1");
    return false;
 
}
```

Comment: tu validacion es en PHP o javascript?

Comment: coloca un ejemplo minimo para que te ayudemos

Comment: tengo una duda, quieres una mascara que se vea `__.___.___-_` y escribes sobre ella, o una vez escrita Y validada se actualize el valor del input?ç

Comment: @JackNavaRow mi validacion es javascript y la validacion que hago es esta

Comment: por favor quita ese comentario ya lo agrege a la respuesta

Comment: Te recomiendo que pruebes utilizando : https://github.com/kadumedia/jQuery.rut.chileno

Answer (score 5):

un ejemplo de validacion de **`Rut`** aplicando la formula de calculo del digito verificador chileno,

```js
function checkRut(rut) {
    // Despejar Puntos
    var valor = rut.value.replace('.','');
    // Despejar Guión
    valor = valor.replace('-','');
    
    // Aislar Cuerpo y Dígito Verificador
    cuerpo = valor.slice(0,-1);
    dv = valor.slice(-1).toUpperCase();
    
    // Formatear RUN
    rut.value = cuerpo + '-'+ dv
    
    // Si no cumple con el mínimo ej. (n.nnn.nnn)
    if(cuerpo.length < 7) { rut.setCustomValidity("RUT Incompleto"); return false;}
    
    // Calcular Dígito Verificador
    suma = 0;
    multiplo = 2;
    
    // Para cada dígito del Cuerpo
    for(i=1;i<=cuerpo.length;i++) {
    
        // Obtener su Producto con el Múltiplo Correspondiente
        index = multiplo * valor.charAt(cuerpo.length - i);
        
        // Sumar al Contador General
        suma = suma + index;
        
        // Consolidar Múltiplo dentro del rango [2,7]
        if(multiplo < 7) { multiplo = multiplo + 1; } else { multiplo = 2; }
  
    }
    
    // Calcular Dígito Verificador en base al Módulo 11
    dvEsperado = 11 - (suma % 11);
    
    // Casos Especiales (0 y K)
    dv = (dv == 'K')?10:dv;
    dv = (dv == 0)?11:dv;
    
    // Validar que el Cuerpo coincide con su Dígito Verificador
    if(dvEsperado != dv) { rut.setCustomValidity("RUT Inválido"); return false; }
    
    // Si todo sale bien, eliminar errores (decretar que es válido)
    rut.setCustomValidity('');
}
```

```html
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="rut" name="rut" required oninput="checkRut(this)" placeholder="Ingrese RUT">
        <button type="submit">Validar RUT y Enviar Form</button>
    </form>
```

como se puede observar sera siempre validado al escribir en el input pero puede ser de acuerdo a tus necesidades

merito a https://gist.github.com/rotvulpix/69a24cc199a4253d058c

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/52335)

Comment: por eso coloque el codigo, la validacion del rut chileno es una formula; la cual se esta aplicando alli @x-rw

Comment: porfavor explica mejor que hace tu codigo en general, es muy vago tu comentario inicial, "aqui un ejemplo"

Comment: gracias me sirvió

Answer (score 4):

Te recomiendo que uses **Inputmask**
Creas unas mascara por Js, donde le obligas al usuario a escribir en el formato que tu deseas

```js
$("#test").inputmask({
 mask: "9[9.999.99]-[9|K|k]",
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/css/inputmask.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<html>
<input type="text " id="test">
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta función deja el rut con el formato 
11.111.111-1

```
formatRut:(rut)=>{
        // XX.XXX.XXX-X
        const newRut = rut.replace(/\./g,'').replace(/\-/g, '').trim().toLowerCase();
        const lastDigit = newRut.substr(-1, 1);
        const rutDigit = newRut.substr(0, newRut.length-1)
        let format = '';
        for (let i = rutDigit.length; i > 0; i--) {
          const e = rutDigit.charAt(i-1);
          format = e.concat(format);
          if (i % 3 === 0){
            format = '.'.concat(format);
          }
        }
        return format.concat('-').concat(lastDigit);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui les dejo un codigo bien facilito para agregar los "." y "-" en los rut, no es lo mejor del mundo pero si a alguien le sirve se lo dejo aqui, pero este no funciona en un form action con enter, ademas no valida si el rut es valido o no, solo agrega . y -

```
<input type="text" class="claseRut" id="rut" name="rut" placeholder="Ingrese su RUT">

var rut;

    $('#rut').focusout(function(){
        var div1, div2, div3, div4;
        rut=$(this).val();

        if(rut.length==9){    
            div1=rut.slice(0,2);
            div2=rut.slice(2,5);
            div3=rut.slice(5,8);
            div4=rut.slice(8,9);

            rut=$(this).val(div1 + "." + div2 + "." + div3 + "-" + div4);
        }

        if(rut.length==8){    
            div1=rut.slice(0,1);
            div2=rut.slice(1,4);
            div3=rut.slice(4,7);
            div4=rut.slice(7,8);

            rut=$(this).val(div1 + "." + div2 + "." + div3 + "-" + div4);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Saludos, considera leer por favor [answer], editar y explicar tu código haría que tu aporte sea mejor recibido

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando el plugin [Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask):

```js
Inputmask.extendAliases({
    rut: {
        mask: '(9(.999){2}-K)|(99(.999){2}-K)',
        autoUnmask: true, //para que .val() devuelva sin mascara (sin puntos ni guion)
        keepStatic: true, //para que el formato de mascara mas corta se mantenga hasta que sea necesario el mas largo
        showMaskOnFocus: false, //oculta la mascara en focus
        showMaskOnHover: false, //oculta la mascara en hover
        definitions: {
            'K': {
                validator: '[0-9|kK]',
                casing: 'upper',
            }
        }
    }
});

$('input').inputmask();
```

```html
<input type="text" data-inputmask="'alias': 'rut'">
```

Answer (score -1):

`mask: "9[9.999.999]-[9|A]"`  para tomar en consideracion los RUT que terminan con K.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [answer], edites y agregues una explicación a tu aporte para que quede mas claro como es que esto soluciona el problema expuesto

Answer (score -2):

Algo simple por si te sirve :)

```
Public Function FormatearRut(strRut As String) As String

    Try
        Dim tmpRut As String = ""
        Dim contadorMiles As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = strRut.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1

            If i = strRut.Length - 1 Then
                tmpRut &= "-" & strRut.Substring(i, 1)
                contadorMiles = 0
            Else
                contadorMiles += 1
            End If

            If contadorMiles = 3 Then
                contadorMiles = 0
                tmpRut = "." & strRut.Substring(i, 1) & tmpRut
            Else
                If i <= strRut.Length - 2 Then
                    tmpRut = strRut.Substring(i, 1) & tmpRut
                End If
            End If

        Next

        Return tmpRut

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return strRut
    End Try
```

Comment: Se agradece la ayuda, pero esto no se si le sea de ayuda al OP, si te fijas hace mas de un año que se realizo la pregunta y adicional el OP agregro las etiquetas de javascript y jquery; y no visual basic.